# Modify to achieve inverse insertion sort in python step by step

Tags: python, insertion-sort, inverse

How to modify this such that it starts from the right of the list and sorts until where the counter is.And show step by step before obtaining output.

```
def insertion_sort(list):    
    for index in range(1, len(list)):    
        current_value = list[index]         
        position = index 

        while position > 0 and list[position - 1] > current_value:             
            list[position] = list[position - 1]           
            position = position - 1 

        list[position] = current_value 

list = [88, 90, 5, 19, 23, 41, 2, 83, 60]
insertion_sort(list) 
print(list)
```

Comment: Could provide the expected/desired output of your script?

Comment: the output is 90, 88, 83, 60, 41, 23, 19, 5, 2

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change

```
while position > 0 and list[position - 1] > current_value:
```

to

```
while position > 0 and list[position - 1] < current_value:
```